# FCM Topic Data Only Messages not being received in IoS Physical Devices

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am trying to send an FCM topic message to my React Native mobile app, but they don't seem to be going through. I am using NodeJs as follows and logging the output to show that the message is getting sent successfully (no issues with android):

```js
admin
  .messaging()
  .send({
    data: {
      title,
      body,
      lat: data.Location.Latitude.toString(),
      lng: data.Location.Longitude.toString(),
    },
    android: {
      priority: "high",
      data: {
        sound: "alert",
      },
    },
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
      headers: {
        'apns-push-type': 'background',
        'apns-priority': '5',
        'apns-topic': 'com.xxxx', 
      },
    },
    topic: topic,
  })
```

The react app is subscribed to the topic as follows:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    await requestUserPermissions();

    messaging().subscribeToTopic(Config.INCIDENTS_TOPIC);
    messaging().onMessage(sendMessage);
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(sendMessage);
  });

  const sendMessage = (remoteMessage) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      notificationRadiusCalculationService.sendMessage(remoteMessage);
    }
  };
```

I have set a breakpoint in the sendMessage and its never being hit.My APN was registered in firebase.